# Can python code be embeded into the google app script (Gmail add-on)?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I have python code that uses Gmail API for fetching unread emails and adding labels according to some rules.
The code runs on my computer and I wish to create a Gmail add-on for this labeling, the add-on should include a new button in the Gmail interface.
The problem is that Google add-on uses google app script.
I want to ask if there is a possibility to embed my python code into the google app script?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can embed it as a string.  However, executing it is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You might use Python with Google Apps Script API to programmatically create and modify a Google Apps Script project, but the Google Apps Script uses V8 as it's runtime, and it requires JavaScript.

You might use Google Cloud Run (see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service) or another hosting infrastructure to use Python to use the Card Service to build the add-on user interface and use the Gmail API.

I think that it might be possible to use Google Colaboratory as the hosting infrastructure but I have no idea how convenient it will be compared to use Google Cloud Run.